# Wordpress submenu item doesnt show in dashboard menu - how to fix?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, menu

I want to create a Wordpress plugin with setting pages as menu items in the dashboard menu. The main item is displayed but not the submenu item. Here's the code:

```
function my_plugin_menu() {
   add_menu_page(__('Pluginname','plugin-slug'), __('Pluginname','plugin-slug'), 'manage_options', 'mt-top-level-handle', 'page_function' );
   add_submenu_page('sub-menu1', 'Submenu1', 'Submenu1', 0, 'sub-menu1', 'submenu1_page_function');
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'edit_table_menu' );
```

What could be the reason why the submenu is not displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first arg of `add_submenu_page()` should be the slug of the parent:

```
add_submenu_page(
    'mt-top-level-handle',
    'Submenu1',
    'Submenu1',
    'manage_options',
    'sub-menu1',
    'submenu1_page_function'
);
```

Comment: NB: I changed `0` to `manage_options` (an admin capability) because user levels are deprecated

Comment: Oh wow! Thank you soo much! Now it works. So many parameters are confusing. I thought the 0 stands for the position in the menu :D